# Is it possible to run HCE with a MCU+PN544C3?

Tags: emulation, hce, nxp-microcontroller

We are now developing a device that using a MCU to control a PN544C3 through UART. The device is now can working in SWP SIM card emulation, Reader and P2P mode. We are now thinking if it is possible to run HCE on this device. Most of the articles are discussing HCE on Android. It is hard to find any documents discussing about running HCE on MCU. Is there any suggestion for this idea?

We can find in the User Manual that PN544C3 has some AID routing configuration that include HCE option.